# Indexing with multiple mapping types

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have this mappings file:

```
{
  "type1": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
  },
  "type2": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my classes that use this mapping:

```
@Document(indexName = "cake", type = "type1")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/elasticsearch/config/mappings.json")
public class TypeOneElasticEntity implements Serializable {
}

@Document(indexName = "cake", type = "type2")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/elasticsearch/config/mappings.json")
public class TypeTwoElasticEntity implements Serializable {
}
```

The problem is that when I want to index `TypeTwoElasticEntity`, I get this error:
**Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters "type1"**
So I guess I have to use a second file. But is it possible to put multiple types in one file in this situation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, one `index type` has one mapping. However, the `index types` will no longer be supported and will become deprecated. If you have multiple mappings, then you need to create a **separate index** for each.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)